# How to add module into nginx package

Tags: deb, nginx

I try to add module like the guide in https://serverfault.com/questions/227480/installing-optional-nginx-modules-with-apt-get, But I got error :

`E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

When I try to run

`sudo apt-get source nginx`

Does anyone know what mistake I have done?

TIA

Comment: Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` files, uncomment the `deb-src` lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` files, uncomment the `deb-src` lines.

Then run `sudo apt-get update` and try to use `sudo apt-get source nginx` again.  It should then work to download the source.

(The "Sources" information isn't downloaded for what sources are easily available until you enable then by uncommenting the `deb-src` lines in your apt lists.)

Note you also need the build dependencies - `sudo apt-get build-dep nginx` should help you get those.

Comment: When running 'dpkg-buildpackage -b', I got this error: **error: Unmet build dependencies: libexpat-dev libgd-dev libhiredis-dev libluajit-5.1-dev libmhash-dev libpam0g-dev libperl-dev libssl-dev libxslt1-dev quilt**.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Comment: @Abdul so install them?  `sudo apt-get build-dep nginx`

Comment: I have been thinking, the difference between I add a dynamic module in this way with I compile then install it. I am just a newbie with no basic knowledge of Linux. I just follow the tutorial.

Comment: I have added the module, but the module does not exist in the module section. Do you know why?

Comment: @Abdul without knowing what module you are referring to, or what instructions and commands you used, it's impossible to answer.  Dynamic modules need extra work for inclusion; statically-built-in modules don't.

Comment: I try to add modsecurity module. I edit the debian/rules and add --add-dynamic-module=/opt/ModSecurity-nginx, then run `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot`. No error show up, but the module is not there in the nginx.

Comment: More question, I am using pbuilder. Do you know how to copy the file from inside chroot pbuilder into outside the real home directory?

Thanks

Comment: @Abdul you actually have to create a package for the binary module .so if you're building it with pbuilder. That will produce a .deb for it.  That can get tricky, so I'll have to do a bit of a writeup so people can do this.  (I'm currently at work so I won't get to this for a while...)

Comment: If I do all the building of the deb package inside chroot, then I install it directly from the chroot path. Is that a correct thing to do that?